# Writing language files for Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am writing language file for Tesseract for different font.
And I have finished with image file and box file using a GUI tool [txt2img](http://code.google.com/p/txt2img/downloads/detail?name=setup.exe&can=2&q=).
Can anyone explain me how to write other files required to create .traineddata file?
For example, word-dawg, unicharset, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract Wiki: [TrainingTesseract3](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract)

Comment: @Azuu: Did u come to a solution on writing other file .if yes please share couldn't find a solution